# Subscript out of range when referencing a worksheet in another workbook from a variable

Tags: vba, excel

See picture: http://s12.postimg.org/ov8djtuh9/Capture.jpg

**Context:** Trying to activate a sheet (variable: cSheet) in another workbook and paste data there from copied data from a different workbook. I'm getting a subscript out of range error whenever I try to activate directly using the variable (i.e. Worksheets(Name).Activate) or try to define a worksheet using the variable and then activate it. I've also tried other coding styles, using "With Worksheet" etc. and my code was a lot longer but I started over because every time I fix something, something else goes wrong. So, sticking to the basics. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub GenSumRep()

Dim AutoSR As Workbook
Dim asrSheet As Worksheet
Dim tempWB As Workbook
Dim dataWB As Workbook
Dim SecName As String
Dim oldcell As String
Dim nsName As String
Dim cSheet As Worksheet

Set AutoSR = ActiveWorkbook
Set asrSheet = AutoSR.ActiveSheet

For a = 3 To 10

    SecName = asrSheet.Range("D" & a).Value

    If SecName <> "" Then

    Workbooks.Open Range("B" & a).Value
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    'tempWB.Windows(1).Visible = False

    AutoSR.Activate

    Workbooks.Open Range("C" & a).Value
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook
    'dataWB.Windows(1).Visible = False

    AutoSR.Activate

        'Copy paste data
        For b = 24 To 29
        oldcell = Range("C" & b).Value
            If b = 24 Then
            nsName = Trim(SecName) & " Data"
            Set cSheet = tempWB.Sheets(nsName)
            Else
            nsName = asrSheet.Range("B" & b).Value
            Set cSheet = tempWB.Sheets(nsName)
            End If

        'Copy
        dataWB.Activate
        Range(oldcell).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste
        tempWB.Activate
        cSheet.Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        b = b + 1
        Next b

    End If

a = a + 1

Next a

End Sub
```

Comment: Sheet name is being referenced correctly. "?nsName" in Immediate Window gives correct sheet names.

Comment: Which line specifically gives the error?  Also beware that activating sheets before workbooks is not allowed, although your code looks OK there.  Are you setting the right references on those `Workbooks`?  I would use `Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(Range(...))` instead of relying on the `ActiveWorkbook` to switch.  You can also qualify your calls to `Range` to avoid activating all of these sheets.  Do: `Workbooks.Open asrSheet.Range(...)` instead of the "bare" `Range`.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the first Set cSheet = tempWB.Sheets(nsName). "?nsName" shows correct reference. I tried changing the code and using Worksheets(nsName).Activate but then it highlighted that as the error. It's always whenever I try to select the sheet. I've coded this way for other macros I made; though not perfect, they did the job. I'm stuck at the simplest step for this particular macro for no reason that I can justify.

Comment: There's really only reason you get this error: the name you have provided does not exist in the collection you are referencing.  A couple of causes are **1)** the name is not correct.  It may appear correct but have hidden characters that make it different than the correct value.  Interrogate it by iterating the character codes, **2)** the name is correct but you are looking for it in the wrong workbook.  Verify that your workbook references are what you think they are `?tempWB.Name`

Comment: If you really want to test this, iterate through the `tempWB.Sheets` and print out the `.Name` from there.  One step further, compare those names to `nsName` and print that out as well.  `For Each sht in tempWB.Sheets : Debug.Print(sht.Name) : Debug.Print(sht.Name = nsName) : Next`.

Comment: Thank you. It's referencing the wrong workbook. Also, by the way, when I did Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(Range(...)) as you suggested, it gave me an error on Range(oldcell).Select (for the copying data part in my code) and the error read "method range of object global failed".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only get that error for one reason: **the name your provided does not exist in the collection!**

There are a couple of likely reasons for this based on your code:

- Your `nsName` variable contains hidden characters that make it different even though it appears correct.
- You are looking for the sheet in the wrong workbook.

Based on your comments, **it seems that you are looking in the wrong workbook**. A good way to check out these subscript errors is to iterate the collection and print out the `Names` included therein.

```
Dim sht as Worksheet    
For Each sht In tempWB.Sheets
    Debug.Print sht.Name
Next sht
```

In general, it is desirable to get rid of calls to `Select` and `Activate` so that you are not relying on the interface in order to get objects.  See [this post about avoiding `Select` and `Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more info.

One idea applied to your code is to assign the Workbooks directly without `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Set tempWB = Workbooks.Open(asrSheet.Range("B" & a).Value)
Set dataWB = Workbooks.Open(asrSheet.Range("C" & a).Value)
```

instead of:

```
    Workbooks.Open Range("B" & a).Value
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook
    'tempWB.Windows(1).Visible = False

    AutoSR.Activate

    Workbooks.Open Range("C" & a).Value
    Set dataWB = ActiveWorkbook
    'dataWB.Windows(1).Visible = False
```

Comment: The problem in my case my sheet name was in arabic  so you have to use the sheet name shown to the user